# Git server hooks, check if code is formated

Tags: git, githooks

I am trying to create a git server hook so that unformatted code would not be pushed. In my scenario I want to use clang format to check if the code is formatted correctly. if not the user will receive a message stating they need to format the code before pushing.

we are trying to implement a must format policy at work and this will simply be a safety net.

Comment: Could you give more details about what you tried and what fails please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the client side, you can look at [`wangkuiyi/7379a242f0d4089eaa75`](https://gist.github.com/wangkuiyi/7379a242f0d4089eaa75) which is [Git `pre-commit` hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks) that invokes `clang-format` to reformat C/C++/Objective-C source code.

That gives you an idea on how to write a [server-side `pre-receive` hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks), which will do the same and compare the resulting content with the original content.
See more at "[Git 'pre-receive' hook and 'git-clang-format' script to reliably reject pushes that violate code style conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34254150/6309)"

Answer (score 3):

## Summary

It took me quite a while to piece together from the sparse examples I was able to find, so I figure I'll share what I've come up with as well.

Basically here's what you need to do:

- use an `update` hook (similar to `pre-receive`)
- inspect the branch and commit
- checkout the bare repo to a temp folder
- run the formatter ([Prettier](https://prettier.io/), in this case) on the temp folder
- exit non-zero if files are / would be changed

  - (either from the tool's output or a `git status --work-tree=... --git-dir=...`)

## Example: Prettier + 'update' Hook

Although the `pre-receive` hook is much more googleable, I find that the `update` hook is both easier to use and more flexible. I'm using *Prettier* in this example, but I tried to write to be easy to adapt to any linter / vetter / formatter.

In my case my git user's home directory is `/srv/git-repositories` and the hooks for the project I've set up are at:

```
/srv/git-repositories/my-project.git/hooks/update
```

I've actually tested this, so I know that it works, although it's a bit watered down from what [I'm really using](https://coolaj86.com/articles/server-side-git-hooks-for-code-formatting/).

That said, it covers the basics:

```
ref_name=$1
new_rev=$3

# only check branches, not tags or bare commits
if [ -z $(echo $ref_name | grep "refs/heads/") ]; then
  exit 0
fi

# don't check empty branches
if [ "$(expr "${new_rev}" : '0*$')" -ne 0 ]; then
  exit 0
fi

# Checkout a copy of the branch (but also changes HEAD)
my_work_tree=$(mktemp -d -t git-work-tree.XXXXXXXX) 2>/dev/null
git --work-tree="${my_work_tree}" --git-dir="." checkout $new_rev -f >/dev/null

# Do the formatter check
echo "Checking code formatting..."
pushd ${my_work_tree} >/dev/null
prettier './**/*.{js,css,html,json,md}' --list-different
my_status=$?
popd >/dev/null

# reset HEAD to master, and cleanup
git --work-tree="${my_work_tree}" --git-dir="." checkout master -f >/dev/null
rm -rf "${my_work_tree}"

# handle error, if any
if [ "0" != "$my_status" ]; then
  echo "Please format the files listed above and re-commit."
  echo "(and don't forget your .prettierrc, if you have one)"
  exit 1
fi
```

Although I typically use [gitea](https://gitea.io) for git hosting, I've tested this particular hook with a simple [automated git deploy with ssh](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps), and it should work just as well with GitLab, Gogs, and the like.

## More Info

I offer a little more detail in the blog post I wrote on the matter:

- [Reject Ugly Commits with Server-Side Git Hooks](https://coolaj86.com/articles/server-side-git-hooks-for-code-formatting/)

### Even more...

You may also benefit from some of these other resources:

- [Git Hooks Documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/githooks.txt#L268)
- [Practical Git Secrets Example](https://github.com/dhoer/gitlab-secrets/blob/master/git-hooks/git-secrets.sh#L26)
- [GitHub Platform Git Hook Samples](https://github.com/github/platform-samples/tree/master/pre-receive-hooks)
- [`pre-receive` hook for clang-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33924519/git-pre-receive-hook-and-git-clang-format-script-to-reliably-reject-pushes-t/34254150#34254150) (already linked above)