# Checking out directly from a remote repository in Git on Windows remote repository

Tags: git, hook

I want to use a hook on my server in git to check my code when a push occurs.

I have my code checking solution ready to go.
The problem with git's hooks is that it's hard to check out the latest code from the server's git repository when an update occurs.

How can I checkout directly from a remote repository in a latest git environment?

I found an example code on stackoverflow, but it's 6 years old. I don't know why, but commands like '--work-tree' are not available in my environment. I need another approach.
[Git server hooks, check if code is formated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41274029/git-server-hooks-check-if-code-is-formated)

Answer (score 0):

A simpler version (than the one I mentioned 6 years ago) would be a [`post-receive` hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks) which would set both the `GIT_DIR` (your current [bare repository](https://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/)) and the `WORK_TREE` (the folder where you want to check out your repository)

```
git --git-dir="$GIT_DIR" --work-tree=. -C "$TARGET" restore -- .
```

Replace `$TARGET` by the path where you want your files to be checked out.

Replace [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) with [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) if the Git on your server is older than [Git 2.23 (Q3 2019)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309).

Answer (score 0):

Oops. --work-tree is valid command. The problem is elsewhere.

```
git --work-tree="<somewhere temporary path>" checkout HEAD
```

It works with `gitea` repository on Windows.
When I use `<path> = "D:\check-file\\"` it is not working.
But when I use `<path> = "D:\check-file" or "D:\check-file\\\\"` it is working fine.

Comment: `--work-tree` is more accurately a valid *option* (option to the [`git` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt---work-treeltpathgt) itself)